# react native functional components and hot reloading not working

Tags: react-native

In the middle of making a react native application and I'm experimenting with functional programming within **React Native** and for some reason when I convert the prebuilt code into an arrow function the **HOT RELOADING** responds but doesn't push the changes please help.

Here's the prebuilt code w/ class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Component1 from './app/components/msg/propsMsg'

export default class tutorial extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome a React Native Sandbox!
        </Text>
        <Component1 msg="props MSG"/>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fefefe',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('tutorial', () => tutorial);
```

Here's my attempt at turning it functional

```
const tutorial = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        Welcome a React Native Sandbox!
      </Text>
      <Component1 msg="props MSG 2"/>
      <Text style={styles.instructions}>
        Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
        Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default tutorial
```

Comment: Unfortunately - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8465

Comment: Noooo.. Thank you